"Artsy" European thriller from 80s/90s with lobotomy and evil scientist
I'm trying to find a movie I saw one night on cable TV as a teen in the mid-90's. It was on Bravo, so it was an "artsy" film. It's very stark and European, I believe French but possibly not. 
I remember the very end, where the protagonist is climbing around on strange machinery in a sort of asylum-like place with, I believe- another guy trying to kill him. I also remember some sort of lobotomy going on. 
I think the very last scene is the protagonist walking out of the asylum-like place into the blueish oncoming morning and squeezing between some cement walls to get away.

Film is shot in Prague, I believe.  There is a weird lobotomy scene at the end that matches original posters description.
Trailer says it all...http://www.imdb.com/title/tt0102181/?ref_=nv_sr_2
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kafka_(film)

Are you the same Paul who posted the previous answer about the film Kafka? If so, it'd be better for you to edit one of your answers into the other rather than posting two separate answers.

No need to give same answer by making different accounts, its better to elaborate existing one.

I'm not sure the comment protocol here but thank you @Paul7reno - you got it! Wow been looking for this for decades! Thanks everyone else who commented too .  :)

This sounds like the ending of Brazil from 1985.
Video of the ending here (spoiler alert): 



Charged with treason for abusing his newly acquired position, Sam is restrained to a chair in a large, empty cylindrical room (the interior of a power station cooling tower), to be tortured by his old friend, Jack Lint (Michael Palin), who is wearing a mask seen earlier in Sam's dreams and had previously distanced himself from Sam. [...]
However, this "happy ending" is all a product of Sam's delusions: Sam is still strapped to the chair and observed by Jack and Deputy Minister Mr. Helpmann, who is portrayed along the film as a good friend of Sam's family. Realising that Sam has descended into blissful insanity, the two declare him a lost cause and exit the room. The film ends with Sam sitting in the chair, smiling and singing "Brazil".

The scene with the blue sky and the cement walls could be from one of the protagonists dreams:




You would think! I love that movie!  And it has a similar feel. It's much more stark and dark than Brasil though. But it has that oddness, the use of silence to build tension. It's a reasonable guess but not the movie. Thank you still.
